# Incredibly low GridFS performance using MongoDB 3.0.0 and Mongofiles

Tags: mongodb, macos, osx-yosemite, database, nosql

I have a MongoDB database with a GridFS collection containing hundreds of thousands of files (345,073, to be precise -- and about 100GBs in volume).

On MongoDB 2.6.8 it takes a fraction of a second to list the files using the native `mongofiles` and connecting to `mongod`. This is the command I use:

```
mongofiles --db files list
```

I just brewed and linked MongoDB 3.0.0 and suddenly the same operation takes more than five minutes to complete, if ever it does. I have to kill the query most of the time, as it drives two of my CPU cores to 100%. The log file does not show anything irregular. I rebuilt the indexes to no avail. I also tried the same with my other GridFS collections in other databases, each with millions of files and I encounter the same issue.

Then I uninstalled 3.0.0 and relinked 2.6.8 and everything is back to normal (using the exact same data files).

I am running MongoDB on Yosemite, and I reckon the problem might be platform specific. But is there anything that I have ommited and I should take into consideration? Or have I really discovered a bug that I must report?

Comment: GrdiFS is not a server solution but a driver level implementation. Which language and which driver are you using? Also make sure that you have updated your driver to a recent version as some server communication aspects have changed.

Comment: No language. I didn't even get there with 3. I am using the simple command line mongofiles interface. Sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: Not sure about `mongofiles` off-hand without checking. But various other utilities have been re-written in "Go". That could be a possible cause.

Comment: Can you verify you are using 3.0 mongofiles? Also, can you edit the question to show us all the steps you used to produce the problem? How many files are in GridFS? Are there any slow queries logged by mongod when you list the files?

Comment: @wdberkeley Yes it is Mongofiles 3, and I see nothing abnormal in the log file. Question updated as per your request. Thanks again.

Comment: I would report it as a bug in the TOOLS project. The tools were rewritten in Go for 3.0. Make sure you include lots of detail about what you're doing and what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem here, for me running a mongofiles 2.6 from a docker image fixed the problem, seems they broke something with the rewrite.

Comment: I also reverted to 2.6. The other obvious solution is to use the drivers. I couldn't finally report the bug. Please do so if you have the time.